How to create (or skip) iPhone 5.5' assets
Trying to upload the iPhone version of my app, I faced every single possible issue on creating an iPhone 8 Plus simulator to create 5.5' assets. Unfortunately, my app is based on iOS 17 and seems I'm using quite a few iOS 16-17 features, so downgrading to 15 (the latest iPhone 8 Plus is compatible with) is not an option.
Any known alternative to create these assets on a different simulator or maybe to automate to resizing / clipping from the 6.5 screenshots? Or, since my app won't actually be compatible with iPhone 8 Plus anyway, is it possible to just skip these screenshots at all?
EDIT
I'm aware of this kind of questions.-
iPhone App Submission requires 5.5 inch display screenshots, but Xcode does not offer any simulators for these devices
which is not what I'm asking. I do know how to create an iPhone 8 Plus simulator with iOS 15, my issue is that I cannot run my app on it because I can't downgrade to iOS 15.
ANSWER
Since I cannot add an answer I'll add my solution here in case it's reopened at some point. iPhone 8 has 16/9 aspect ratio, so finally I was able to take the screenshots using a device simulator with the same aspect ratio (but still able to run iOS 17), according to chatGPT this devices are:
iPhone SE (2nd generation) and iPhone SE (3rd generation)

Screen size: 4.7 inches
Resolution: 750 x 1334 pixels
Aspect ratio: 16:9

